# How to add data to multiple lines in a txt file using Notepad++ ,Can it done to similar multiple files too_

Tags: notepad++

Here how the txt file and I have many files with different file names. Only the file names are different but the data fields are exactly the same.

example of what inside of a txt file

---

I need to enter my own data into the above fields after "=" and it should allow me to do these changes to multiple files without opening them. Note: those fields are among dozens of similar text lines. But there are arranged in each line as above.
Thanks!

Comment: Modify 1 file then copy it.This has nothing to do with Notepad++.

Comment: What's an example of the output based on the 3 line input file you showed above?

Comment: hi! Tim,I thiese txt files with different names and they all have different data written.only the fileds are common to all the files.I just need a method to add my own data to those fields without having to open any of the files.